# I don't understand Property 'self.heading' not initialized at super.init call error in my code

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, swiftui

I created a class to get the current heading with CLLocationManagerDelegate for my SwiftUI app, but I have the `Property 'self.heading' not initialized at super.init call` error. I don't know why. I do not think I need to specify a parameter because my class does not take any parameters during its call ?

My LocationManager class:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {

  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
  var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  @Published var heading: Double {
    willSet {
      objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }

  override init() {
    super.init()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager!.delegate = self
    locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.heading = newHeading.trueHeading.degreesToRadians
  }

}
```

[image: Screen of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **MUST** initial all instance variables of the current class **before** initializing the *super*.

So add some initial value to `heading` before calling `super.init()` like:

```
override init() {
    heading = 0 // Or anything you need
    super.init()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager!.delegate = self
    locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```